# Windows API to subscribe for VoIP activities like "Sound -> Communications" does?

Tags: windows

Situation: at Windows "Control Panel", you can visit "Sound" widget and switch to "Communications" tab. There, you can configure how much %% the OS should reduce all other sounds if we have incoming VoIP call ringing (to not miss the call, indeed).

Question: is there any API that allows a developer to subscribe and react on such events too? (let say, auto-pause your game app, or "do not disturb" auto-status for the call duration in your messenger app, or any other smart thing you can do for better user experience).

Note: I'm looking for OS-wide API, not "SDK for VoIP app X only".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Microsoft term for this is [Custom Ducking Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940517(v=vs.85).aspx). The seemingly-odd name is explained by the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducking) on ducking:

> Ducking is an audio effect commonly used in radio and pop music,
>   especially dance music. In ducking, the level of one audio signal is
>   reduced by the presence of another signal. In radio this can typically
>   be achieved by lowering (ducking) the volume of a secondary audio
>   track when the primary track starts, and lifting the volume again when
>   the primary track is finished. A typical use of this effect in a daily
>   radio production routine is for creating a voice-over: a foreign
>   language original sound is dubbed (and ducked) by a professional
>   speaker reading the translation. Ducking becomes active as soon as the
>   translation starts.

From the MSDN, the [APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940392(v=vs.85).aspx) you need to implement custom ducking behavior are COM-based. In summary:

> - [MMDevice API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316556(v=vs.85).aspx) for multimedia device enumeration and selection.
> - [WASAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455(v=vs.85).aspx) for accessing the communications capture and render device, stream management operations, and handling ducking events.
> - [WAVE APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713499(VS.85).aspx) for accessing the communications device and capturing audio input.

Code samples to implement the functionality you want are available at the respective MSDN pages.